# Run-time error '91'; Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

Im getting the following error:

> "Run-time error '91';  Object variable or With block variable not set"

From this particular code written in method "CreateArray()", when it's called from within the `NewEntry()` method:

```
    With NameStart
    n = Range(.Offset(1, 0), .End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End With
```

### Original Code:

```
Sub CreateArray()

With NameStart
    n = Range(.Offset(1, 0), .End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End With

ReDim PhoneName(n)

For i = 1 To n
    PhoneName(i) = NameStart.Offset(i, 0)
    PhoneNumber(i) = NumStart.Offset(i, 0)
Next i
End Sub
```

### Next method:

```
Sub NewEntry()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Phone Data").Activate

NewName = InputBox("Please enter the new entry name using the " _
& "following format: Last, First", "New Name", "Smith, John")
If NewName = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a name."
    Exit Sub
End If

NewNumber = InputBox("Please enter the 10-digit phone number for " _
        & NewName & " usin the following format: 1234567890", _
        "New Number", 1234567890)
        If NewNumber / 10 ^ 10 < 0.1 Or NewNumber / 10 ^ 10 > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a 10-digit number."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Call CreateArray
            For i = 1 To n
                If PhoneName(i) = NewName Then
                MsgBox "There is already an entry for this person in the " _
                & "phone book."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i

    NameStart.Offset(n, 0).Value = NewName
    NumStart.Offset(n, 0).Value = NewNumber
    Range(NameStart, NumStart.Offset(n, 0)).Select
        Selection.Sort Key1:=NameStart, Order1:=xlAscending
    Worksheets("Phonebook Welcome").Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox NewName & " has been added to the phone book."
End Sub
```

### Variable Declaration:

```
Public i As Integer
Public n As Integer
Private PhoneName() As String
Private PhoneNumber() As Double
Public NewName As String
Public NewNumber As Double
Public NameStart As Range
Public NumStart As Range
```

Comment: Are there any methods which set the value of `NameStart`?

Comment: No. The only interaction is done with the button(shape) that calles NewEntry()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring `Public NameStart As Range` doesn't actually make `NameStart` refer to any actual range on any worksheet. Before you can use can call methods on  `NameStart`, you need to set it to refer to an actual range, like this:

`Set NameStart = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10")`

If you happen to have defined a named range called "NameStart" then you would still need to link that to the `NameStart` variable:

`Set NameStart = Range("NameStart")`

If you don't do this then `NameStart` isn't linked to anything and attempting to call methods on it will produce a run-time error

Comment: Ok i just create a named range "NameStart", but is there any method in VBA that executes only once. Since i need to apped phone numbers at the end of list as it apperas here: [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/152yv52.png[/IMG]

Comment: `Set NameStart = Worksheets("Phone Data").Range("B6")` and `Set NumStart = Worksheets("Phone Data").Range("C6")` look like they would work for the spreadsheet in the image. Put those at the start of the `NewEntry` sub